# PHP loops to MYSQL Select Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table in my database and I currently have a calender display over 7 days. This allows user to place jobs and comments inside the day boxes. My current script has been outgrown and the time it takes the loops is too long. I was wondering if I could swap out the current looping with a SELECT Query or just a better structure.

**CODE EXAMPLE NOW**

```
    $reg = array("200+ Reg name");$date = array(7 days)

    foreach($reg as $r) {
    foreach($date as $d){

                  $sql = "SELECT JOBS WHERE reg='$r' AND date='$d'";
                  $sql2 = "SELECT COMMENTS WHERE reg='$r' AND date='$d'";
                        }
                        }
```

As you can see with over 200 `$reg` the loops goes wild!

**MY TWO TABLES**

comments_db

```
+------+----------+------------+-------------------+----------+
|  id  |   name   |    date    |      detail       |   reg    |
+------+----------+------------+-------------------+----------+
| 2121 | john doe | 2015-12-16 | these are details | VX77 8GH |
+------+----------+------------+-------------------+----------+
```

job_db

```
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+---------------+--+
|  id  |   reg    | date_range1 | date_range2 |         date_individual          |    details    |  |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+---------------+--+
| 2121 | PF33 3HG | 2015-12-16  | 2015-12-17  | null                             | this is a job |  |
|  323 | FG15 5NN | null        | null        | 2015-12-16,2015-12-17,2015-12-19 | job info      |  |
+------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------+---------------+--+
```

**Calender Display goes Monday to Sun**

```
 +------+------------------+---------------------+------+------------------+-------------+--+
    | reg  |       Mon        |        Tues         | Wed  |       Thu        |     Fri     |  |
    +------+------------------+---------------------+------+------------------+-------------+--+
    | reg1 | Job, job,comment | job,job             | job  | job              | comment,job |  |
    | reg1 | job,job,job      | comment,job,comment | job, | comment, comment |             |  |
    +------+------------------+---------------------+------+------------------+-------------+--+
```

Any advice?

Comment: Select all `jobs` and `comments` prior to the loop into an array, then sort it by `day` (or `date`, whatever you use) as a key. Then you'll have another loop that just prints the data. **Conclusion**: 1 or 2 queries instead of `RegMembers*Days*2` queries, no nested loops.

Comment: @OfirBaruch thats not a bad theory, as it stops 1000's of queries and just loops plain text so i can match if up with php functions... hmmm

Comment: May I offer it as an answer?

Comment: Dates in SQL adhere to a specific format. This isn't it

Comment: assume you are looking at 2015-01-01 then @Strawberry

Comment: @OfirBaruch you can, i'll accept, the tests i have just done a looking tip top!

Comment: @Brobina If 01 is a month and 01 is a day, then yes.

Comment: You could combine both of the in to one query!

Comment: @user3633383 im sure someone can, I can't ;)

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM JOBS, COMMENTS WHERE JOBS.reg='$r' AND JOBS.date='$d' AND COMMENTS.reg='$r' AND COMMENTS.date='$d'";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your current code.
You have a nested loop, the main loop is per `reg` and the second (nested) loop is per `day`. Without further conditions, it means `reg`*`day` loops.
Inside the nested loop you're having 2 SQL queries, so you're having `2*loops` queries anytime this page is being loaded.

As a first step, I'll recommend to take the queries out of the loop and basically fetch all the requested rows (I saw you have a date range column, so maybe you can filter the rows to the specific date range).

Furthermore, you can try and combine those 2 queries into one "complex" query. After that, fetch the data and sort it by `day`, so you'll have one big array in the following structure (an example, not real code):

```
$data[xday]['comments'][i] = $commentsDataArray;
$data[xday]['jobs'][i] = $commentsDataArray;
```

Where `xday` is a number that represents the day 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
and `i` is just an increasing number.

Now you can loop through this array and print the data.